# On initial login on local site getting anti-forgery cookie token error, when try second time it is ok

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, csrf, antiforgerytoken

Please bare in mind that I already put a machine key in both of my project's web.config files and I already checked that there is no multiple @Html.AntiForgeryToken() as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788912/deploying-antiforgerytoken-error). I have two projects developed in Asp.Net 4, when deployed locally give me fallowing error on first attempt and there is no problem on second time. I also delete the cookies and browsing history, just to make sure but same result.

**Internal Server Error**

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is
>   hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running
>   the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the 
>   configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys.
>   AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

```
System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryTokenStore.GetCookieToken(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__16(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
```

Comment: Got this error when added '<httpCookies domain=".domain.com"/>' into the 'web.config'. After removing the 'httpCookies' section the error was gone. Have no idea what kind of dependency it has. My project is ASP MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. I have another virtual directory for webapi under main application. I checked there is only one token in the page source and having same machine key in both Main app and webapi.