# C# Web API & Android app - Error anti-forgery token could not be decrypted on POST with Cookie

Tags: c#, android, post, cookies, antiforgerytoken

Ok, continuing from my previous question, where I stated that adding a Cookie to an Android HttpPost isn't that hard: It is hard(er than I thought)..

I use the following HttpPost method in my Android app:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
    String response = "";
    for(String url : urls){
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        try{
            URL u = new URL(url);
            String baseUrl = u.getProtocol() + "://" + u.getHost();

            // POST-request requires anti-forgery Cookie
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(baseUrl);
            post.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);

            // POST-request requires cookieToken, provider and returnUrl
            String[] cookieStrings = cookie.split("=");
            List<NameValuePair> nvPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(cookieStrings[0], cookieStrings[1]));
            nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("provider", "Google"));
            nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("returnUrl", baseUrl));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPairs));

            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(post);

            // Get the response of the POST-request
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String s = "";
            while((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                response += s;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

When I debug the `response`, I'm getting the following error:

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is
>   hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running
>   the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey>
>   configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys.
>   AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I've Googled this error and found [this link](http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.nl/2013/08/how-to-solve-anti-forgery-token-could.html). Here they add a `machineKey` to the C# `Web.config`. I checked and this `machineKey` is already present in my C# project of the Web API.

So, reading the error above, I believe it's caused because I'm just running `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` requests from the Android App (which is the *`Web Farm or cluster`* part? Am I correct in this?

And more importantly, how do I fix this error in Android so I can send my `Cookie` + `CookieToken` successfully, so I'm logged in with the `POST-request`. Cause then I can start using `GET-requests` that are `[Authorized]` from the same `DefaultHttpClient`.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

---

Edit 1:

After reading the answers from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788912/deploying-antiforgerytoken-error):

- I don't have more than one `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on one page.
- The `machineKey` was already added to the `Web.config` as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this error is solved.. Turned out I had three cookies instead of one, so with the string-split I had part of the next cookie with the string token. So that's solved now by getting all cookies separately (splitting with ";"), and then splitting the correct cookie with "=" to send it.

After I did that however, if received a next error:

> Validation of the provided anti-forgery token failed. The cookie
>   "__RequestVerificationToken" and the form field
>   "__RequestVerificationToken" were swapped.

But at least I can continue again and the error above is solved.